# Floating TextField Vertical Axis?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an animated floating text field that works well for horizontal axis.  I want to modify the same one so it can support both horizontal & vertical axis.  Currently, the offset used and animated looks great for horizontal lines but does not deal with the dynamic nature of a `.vertical` axis.

[image]

The code for the floatingTextField is below:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FloatingTextField: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var text: String
    var axis: Axis = .horizontal
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(text.isEmpty ? Color(.placeholderText) : .accentColor)
                .offset(y: text.isEmpty ? 0 : -25)
                .scaleEffect(text.isEmpty ? 1 : 0.75, anchor: .leading)
            TextField("", text: $text, axis: axis)
        }
        .padding(.top, 15)
        .animation(.spring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.3), value: text)
    }
}
```

Its usage is seen in this code block here:

```swift
FloatingTextField(title: "Address", text: item.location.address)
FloatingTextField(title: "Notes", text: item.notes, axis: .vertical)
```

I would like the `.horizontal` to remain with the same feel & functionality but I would very much like the `.vertical` to work as expected as well.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really tell you why this works, but it works....

```
import SwiftUI

struct FloatingTextField: View {
let title: String
@Binding var text: String
var axis: Axis = .horizontal

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(text.isEmpty ? Color(.placeholderText) : .accentColor)
                .offset(y: text.isEmpty ? 5 : -20)
                .scaleEffect(text.isEmpty ? 1 : 0.75, anchor: .leading)
        }
        TextField("", text: $text, axis: axis)
            .lineLimit(5)
    }
    .padding(.top, 15)
    .animation(.spring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.3), value: text)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay you did everything right but you missed only the alignment of `ZStack`

change `ZStack(alignment: .leading)` to `ZStack(alignment: .topLeading)`